# Whose "move" is Lock referring to?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), Morpheus team blows EMP to disable sentinels inside Zion. Then under the
direction of Commander Lock, Zion operator bought back system online and
sealed the shaft. So Commander Lock looks up and say:

> Commander Lock: Your **move**.

Whose "move" is Lock referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lock is talking to the commander of the Machine armies. Note that he has no expectation of being heard.

> INT. ZION - NIGHT:
> A thick cloud of earth is coughed from the opening near the
> top of Zion.
>
> INT. ZION - COMMAND CENTER - NIGHT -
> The rumble from the explosion slowly fades. **Lock stares up at
> the dark cave ceiling, talking to his enemy as one might talk
> to God.**
>
> **LOCK:** *Your move.*
>
> <sub><sup>Matrix Revolutions: Screenplay</sup></sub>